# WCF AsyncPattern + Task<T>.Factory.FromAsync = ContextSwitchDeadlock

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to simplify a call to a WCF async operation by wrapping the call into a Task on the client side with Task.Factory.FromAsync. But when I Start() the wrapped Task, the call to Start() blocks the client until the debugger reports a ContextSwitchDeadlock. The server side operation gets invoked correctly, though. What am I missing?

WCF contract:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "urn:test/test")]
public interface ITestContract
{
    [OperationContract(AsyncPattern=true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginGetResult(AsyncCallback callback, object state);

    int EndGetResult(IAsyncResult result);
}
```

Client code:

```
var task = Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(
    (callback, state) => service.BeginGetResult(callback, state),
    (result) => service.EndGetResult(result)
);
task.Start(); // blocks until ContextSwitchDeadlock gets reported
```

EDIT: Just for the sake of completeness: No, I can't use the .NET 4.5 async / await pattern because .NET 4.0 (i.e. Windows XP and Server 2003 support) is a hard requirement for my project.

EDIT2:

The call to `Start()` should not be necessary anyway. The real problem is that `BeginGetResult` does not get invoked on the server side until I call `Start()`, `Wait()` or `Result` - which amount to the same thing as a synchronous call.

As I found out, this has nothing to do with Tasks at all. If I do the following, I get the same results:

```
var asyncResult = service.BeginGetResult(null, null); // BeginGetResult NOT invoked on server side!
asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(); // Now BeginGetResult actually gets invoked
```

EDIT3:

Turns out that it was all just a misunderstanding on my part. I expected that calling `BeginGetResult` on the client side would *immediately* call the corresponding `BeginGetResult` on the server side, i.e. that `BeginGetResult` on the client side would block until the server actually gets a request, but that does not seem to be the case. Apparently the request is sent in a background thread, so there may be a delay between the client and server side call to `BeginGetResult`. I suppose this behavior is to be expected, so everthing is fine :-).

Comment: You can use the [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) library (currently a Release Candidate) to add `async`/`await` support to .NET 4.0 projects.

Comment: Thanks, looks interesting! I'm not sure if I want Beta stuff in production code, though.

Comment: I understand. FWIW, `async` was incredibly mature (and well-documented) even at the CTP stage; it's the only pre-release MS software I used in production.

Comment: I think your edit doesn't make much sense. There is no way `WaitOne()` can cause the invocation to actually start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to call `Start` on a `Task` created by `FromAsync`. `Start` is only for tasks with code, and a `FromAsync` task does not have any code.

Comment: Right - but strangley, unless I call task.Start(), task.Wait() or task.Result, nothing seems to happen on the server side.

Comment: If you're not using `async`, then you do need to use `Wait`, `Result`, or a task continuation. If your client just exits (quickly) then it is possible that the server won't see the call.

Comment: The problem is that `BeginGetResult` never gets invoked before I call `Wait` or `Result` - which amounts to the same thing as a synchronous call.

Comment: It definitely should be called at the point of `FromAsync`. Are you using the default VS client proxy?

Comment: I am using a shared assembly instead of a generated client proxy. I create the proxy programmatically using a `ChannelFactory<ITestContract>`.

Comment: Actually the problem has nothing to do with Tasks at all, see edit.

Comment: It looks like the problem is with your proxy.

Comment: Actually there was just a problem with my understanding of the async programming model, see edit.

Comment: In fact, this comment hit the mark: "your client just exits (quickly) then it is possible that the server won't see the call.". I just was too stupid to get that point :-).